# Discord.py V2 Giveaway Command Not Working

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am making a discord.py giveaway command. It puts the winners into the list 'winners' and then it's supposed to announce them. My issue is that I can print the winners to the terminal but I can't get the bot to mention the winners in the message it sends.

This is the code I am using:

```
@commands.hybrid_command(name='startgive')
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def startgive(self, ctx: commands.Context, prize: str, duration: str, total_winners: int, *, channel: discord.TextChannel):
    await ctx.send(f"Giveaway created in <#{channel.id}> for {prize}, and will last {duration}.")
    duration_seconds = convert(duration)

    embed = discord.Embed(title = f"{prize} Giveaway!", color = ctx.author.color)
    embed.add_field(name='Ends', value=f"{duration}", inline = False)
    embed.add_field(name = "Hosted by:", value = ctx.author.mention, inline = False)
    embed.add_field(name='Winners', value=f"{total_winners}", inline = False)

    my_msg = await channel.send(embed = embed)
    await my_msg.add_reaction("")

    await asyncio.sleep(duration_seconds)

    new_msg = await channel.fetch_message(my_msg.id)

    users = []
    for reaction in new_msg.reactions:
        if reaction.emoji == '':
            async for user in reaction.users():
                if user != self.bot.user:
                    users.append(user.mention)

    if len(users) < total_winners:
            winners_number = len(users)
    else:
        winners_number = total_winners

    winners = []
    for i in range(winners_number):
        user = random.randint(0, winners_number)
        if users[user] not in winners:
            winners.append(users[user])

    print(', '.join(winners)) #This line is used to simply show that the winners array does hold a value of a user being mentioned
    
    updatedEmbed = discord.Embed(title = f"{prize} Giveaway!", color = ctx.author.color)
    updatedEmbed.add_field(name = "Hosted by:", value = ctx.author.mention, inline = False)
    updatedEmbed.add_field(name = "Winners:", value = f"{', '.join(winners)}", inline = False)
    updatedEmbed.set_footer(text = f"Ended", inline = False)
    await my_msg.edit(embed=updatedEmbed)

    await channel.send(f"Congratulations! {', '.join(winners)} won {prize}! Thank you for participating.")


def convert(time):
    pos = ["s","m","h","d"]

    time_dict = {"s" : 1, "m" : 60, "h" : 3600 , "d" : 3600*24}

    unit = time[-1]

    if unit not in pos:
        return -1
    try:
        val = int(time[:-1])
    except:
        return -2

    return val * time_dict[unit]
```

Comment: What do you mean with "can't get the bot to do this"? What happens instead? What error are you getting?

Comment: @stijndcl
Quite literally it does nothing. It just doesn't announce the winners or update the old embed with the new one. I would presume that there is something wrong with the mentioning of the user(s) who won.

Comment: If it gets to that print but doesn't send the message in Discord then it must error. Did you set up logging? Are you swallowing errors in an error handler?

Comment: @stijndcl That's the thing. I have error handlers but those all also send a message if they are used. I seriously don't know why it's doing this and since I can't read an error I really don't have an idea on where to go from here.